# HttpClient Sequential calls connection error

Tags: c#, post, get, dotnet-httpclient

I’ve got a process that POSTS an HTTP request out to a vendor obtains the session token then runs a sequential GET request. I’m getting a “Connection Error” without much output. The secondary GET returns a response if I don’t submit both in sequence, but fails as there is no session token from the first request. It seems both run individually, but fail when running after one another. I should be ok reusing the “client” which actually seems better online. I’m wondering if it has something to do with the Tasks and Awaits. Any suggestions help!

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace actIntegration {
    public class actApi {

        // Static Encoura and mail variables.
        public string username = "**********";
        public string password = "**********";
        public string email = "**********";
        public string xApiKey = "**********";
        public string sessionToken = "";
        public string organizationUid = "";

        /**
         * Converts payload object to JSON string.
         *  
         * @return  string - Response from Encoura.
         */
        public async Task<string> getActUploadFile() {
            // Create the current client instance for Http requests.
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {
                string response = string.Empty;
                JObject responseData = new JObject();

                var payload = new {
                    userName = username,
                    password = password,
                    acceptedTerms = true
                };

                // Convert JSON object to JSON string.
                dynamic json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);

                try {
                    response = await encouraLogin(client, json);

                    // Convert JSON response string back to a JSON object to parse and search for the token. 
                    responseData = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);

                    sessionToken = responseData["sessionToken"].Value<string>();
                    organizationUid = responseData["user"]["organizations"][0]["uid"].Value<string>();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Capture additional data for the sendErrorEmail() function.
                    string data = "ERROR: " + response.ToString();

                    // Send error information to email function.
                    sendErrorEmail(e, data);
                }

                try {
                    response = await getExportList(client);

                    // Convert JSON export response string back to a JSON object to parse and search for the exports download URL. 
                    responseData = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Capture additional data for the sendErrorEmail() function.
                    string data = "ERROR: " + response.ToString();

                    // Send error information to email function.
                    sendErrorEmail(e, data);
                }

                return responseData.ToString();
            }
        }

        /** 
         * Get token via API request. 
         * See the web api documentation at https://helpcenter.encoura.org/hc/en-us/articles/360037582012-API-Documentation-for-Automating-Downloads-of-ACT-Score-Reports-
         * 
         * @param   json - JSON key/value collection string used for sending data through to the Encoura API as settings/options.
         * 
         * @return  string - Response from Encoura Authorization API POST.
         */
        public async Task<string> encouraLogin(HttpClient client, dynamic json) {
            string response = string.Empty;

            try {
                // Geth Authorization via supplied arguments. 
                response = await getAuthorization(client, json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Capture additional data for the sendErrorEmail() function.
                string data = "ERROR:" + response.ToString();

                // Send error information to email function.
                sendErrorEmail(e, data);
            }

            return response;            
        }

        /** 
         * Appends the bearer authorization token to the current HttpClient request.         
         * 
         * @param   client - Current class instance used for sending and receiving HTTP request/responses.
         * @param   json - Payload fro authentication.
         *  
         * @return  N/A - Adds the authorization bearer token to the header of the current client.
         */
        public async Task<string> getAuthorization(HttpClient client, dynamic json) {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            string sResponse = string.Empty;

            try {
                // Add application/json, x-api-key to the header of the current client.          
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", xApiKey);

                // Add application/json to the header of the current client.
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                // Convert object to HttpContent for POST.
                StringContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                // Post authorization information to the client.
                response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.datalab.nrccua.org/v1/login", content);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                // Client response.
                sResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Capture additional data for the sendErrorEmail() function.
                string data = "ERROR - StatusCode:" + response.StatusCode + ", ReasonPhrase: " + response.ReasonPhrase + ", Response content = " + sResponse;

                // Send error information to email function.
                sendErrorEmail(e, data);
            }

            return sResponse;
        }

        /** 
        * Get export list via API request. 
        * 
        * @return  string - Response from Encoura.
        */
        public async Task<string> getExportList(HttpClient client) {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            string sResponse = string.Empty;

            try {
                // Add application/json, x-api-key, JWT and Organization to the header of the current client.          
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", xApiKey);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "JWT " + sessionToken);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Organization", organizationUid);

                // Add application/json to the header of the current client.
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                // Get export information from encoura.
                UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder("https://api.datalab.nrccua.org/v1/datacenter/exports");
                builder.Query = "productKey=score-reporter&status=NotDelivered";
                response = await client.GetAsync(builder.Uri);

                //response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.datalab.nrccua.org/v1/datacenter/exports?productKey=score-reporter&status=NotDelivered");

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                // Client response.
                sResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Capture additional data for the sendErrorEmail() function.
                string data = "ERROR - StatusCode:" + response.StatusCode + ", ReasonPhrase: " + response.ReasonPhrase + ", Response content = " + sResponse;

                // Send error information to email function.
                sendErrorEmail(e, data);

                return data;
            }

            return sResponse;
        }

        /**
         * Error function which emails Exception information and details of the error to the ITS-Process@usd.edu mailbox.
         *
         * @param   e - Exception information passed to the function.
         * @param   data - Additional data captured for output.
         * 
         * @return  N/A void
         */
        public void sendErrorEmail(Exception e, string additionalData = "No additoinal data supplied.") {
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage o = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(
                "**********",
                "**********; **********",
                "Error - Encoura Connection",
                "Data: \n" + e.Data + "\n\n" +
                "HelpLink: \n" + e.HelpLink + "\n\n" +
                "HResult: \n" + e.HResult + "\n\n" +
                "InnerException: \n" + e.InnerException + "\n\n" +
                "Message: \n" + e.Message + "\n\n" +
                "Source: \n" + e.Source + "\n\n" +
                "StackTrace: \n" + e.StackTrace + "\n\n" +
                "TargetSite: \n" + e.TargetSite + "\n\n" +
                "Additional Data: \n" + additionalData
            );

            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtpobj = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("**********", 25);
            smtpobj.EnableSsl = false;
            smtpobj.Send(o);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There server may be refusing a second connection from same user.   It looks like you have a using block which should dispose the request at end.  But you have in a Async block so second block is running in parallel with first.  I would try to remove the Async.

Comment: @jdweng I'm missing the code that would run in parallel in his getActUploadFile method.  Could you explain more where you think it's running in parallel?

Comment: Are you sure the login and authentication didn't just fail?  You're eating the exception from a failed login.

Comment: What do you think ASYNC does?

Comment: @jdweng What do you think `await` does? :)

Comment: Login/Auth works, I can run the POST by itself and retrieve the session token and UID I need for the sequential GET. I can run the GET and retrieve the response stating the login failed as the GET relies on the POST response for the session token and UID. But when trying to run both in sequence I'm having the issue.

Comment: I've also tried separate client instances, and a few other things, but no luck as of yet.

Comment: Await needs to be outside the Async to work.  You have them inside.

Comment: @jdweng Huh? The awaits mean that `encouraLogin` is run to completion before `getExportList` is invoked. If you doubt that, I recommend an async/await tutorial: this is pretty basic stuff

Comment: @canton7 : Did you look at the code?  For example getActUploadFile is Async so it runs in parallel with encouraLoginand getAuthorization and getExportList and sendErrorEmail

Comment: @jdweng That's not what `async` means. `async` just means that you're allowed to use `await` inside the method: it doesn't mean anything about whether the methods run in parallel or not. To determine that, you need to look at the awaits. If each Task-returning method is `awaited` straight away, everything will run in sequence. If several Task-returning methods are called after each other without any awaits, then the Tasks awaited later, you can get them running in parallel. I recommend trying this yourself, and reading some beginner tutorials.

Comment: @canton7 : Async means the block of code does not wait for completion before running next block of code.  AWait are normally in front of an Async method, not inside the method.

Comment: @jdweng No, you're wrong. Please go and research this -- you're a high-rep user, and spouting completely false statements as fact is not helpful. You can *only* place await statements inside an async method -- the very reason for marking a method async is so that you can use awaits in it! You can await any Task (and more things besides), regardless of whether it was produced from an async method, or something else (such as a `TaskCompletionSource`, or just `Task.CompletedTask`)

Comment: @canton7 : What prevents with the posted code for two request to be made before a response is returned from the first?

Comment: @jdweng Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225619/discussion-between-canton7-and-jdweng).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple things to separate the calls and make sequential requests for readability I've had to revert to making the requests all within the same method. I can't be sure what is/wasn't being passed from global variables to passed parameters.

I've updated the code to the following:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;using System;using System.Net.Http;using System.Net.Http.Headers;using System.Text;using System.Threading.Tasks;namespace actIntegration {
public class actApi {
    // Create the current client instance for Http requests.
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    // Static Encoura and mail variables.
    public string username = "**********";
    public string password = "**********";
    public string email = "**********";
    public string xApiKey = "**********";

    /**
     * Converts payload object to JSON string.
     *  
     * @return  string - Response from Encoura.
     */
    public async Task<string> getActUploadFile() {
        string response = string.Empty;
        JObject responseData = new JObject();

        var payload = new {
            userName = username,
            password = password,
            acceptedTerms = true
        };

        // Convert JSON object to JSON string.
        dynamic json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);

        try {
            response = await getExport(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Capture additional data for the sendErrorEmail() function.
            string data = "ERROR: " + response.ToString();

            // Send error information to email function.
            sendErrorEmail(e, data);
        }

        return response;            
    }

    /** 
     * Appends the bearer authorization token to the current HttpClient request.         
     * 
     * @param   client - Current class instance used for sending and receiving HTTP request/responses.
     * @param   json - Payload fro authentication.
     *  
     * @return  N/A - Adds the authorization bearer token to the header of the current client.
     */
    public async Task<string> getExport(dynamic json) {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        string sResponse = string.Empty;
        JObject responseData = new JObject();

        try {
            /* Authorization Request */
            // Add x-api-key to the header of the current client.          
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", xApiKey);

            // Add application/json to the header of the current client.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // Convert object to HttpContent for POST.
            StringContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            // Post authorization information to the client.
            response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.datalab.nrccua.org/v1/login", content);

            // Validate POST response success.
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // Client response.
            sResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // Deserialize Object to get response data for sequential request.
            responseData = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sResponse);

            /* Get Export(s) List Request */
            // Add Authorization and Organization from previous request to the header of the current client.    
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "JWT " + responseData["sessionToken"].Value<string>());
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Organization", responseData["user"]["organizations"][0]["uid"].Value<string>());

            // Build GET request and get export information from encoura.
            UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder("https://api.datalab.nrccua.org/v1/datacenter/exports");
            builder.Query = "productKey=score-reporter&status=NotDelivered";
            response = await client.GetAsync(builder.Uri);

            // Validate GET response success.
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                // Client response.
                sResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Capture additional data for the sendErrorEmail() function.
            string data = "ERROR - StatusCode:" + response.StatusCode + ", ReasonPhrase: " + response.ReasonPhrase + ", Response content = " + sResponse;

            // Send error information to email function.
            sendErrorEmail(e, data);
        }

        return sResponse;
    }

    /**
     * Error function which emails Exception information and details of the error to the ITS-Process@usd.edu mailbox.
     *
     * @param   e - Exception information passed to the function.
     * @param   data - Additional data captured for output.
     * 
     * @return  N/A void
     */
    public void sendErrorEmail(Exception e, string additionalData = "No additoinal data supplied.") {
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage o = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(
            "**********",
            "**********,
            "Error - Encoura Connection",
            "Data: \n" + e.Data + "\n\n" +
            "HelpLink: \n" + e.HelpLink + "\n\n" +
            "HResult: \n" + e.HResult + "\n\n" +
            "InnerException: \n" + e.InnerException + "\n\n" +
            "Message: \n" + e.Message + "\n\n" +
            "Source: \n" + e.Source + "\n\n" +
            "StackTrace: \n" + e.StackTrace + "\n\n" +
            "TargetSite: \n" + e.TargetSite + "\n\n" +
            "Additional Data: \n" + additionalData
        );

        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtpobj = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("**********", 25);
        smtpobj.EnableSsl = false;
        smtpobj.Send(o);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What status code are you actually getting back?